# How to make a double entry grid with winforms?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I am using Winforms and Infragistics. My goal is to create a gui to manage user rights for my application.

In my database, I have a table with the following fields :

[RightAssignmentID] [UserID] [RightID]

which associates users and rights.

In my application, I would like to create a double entry grid with users on the left column, rights on the top line and checkboxes on the rest of the grid that determines whether the corresponding user owns the corresponding right or not.

As far as I know you cannot directly make that kind of grids with Winforms, so I was considering using a pivot query to generate the layout I need for my data. 
Here are my results :

```
SELECT
[1] as 'right1',[2] as 'right2',[3] as 'right3',[4] as 'right4',[5] as 'right5'
  FROM [dbo].[RightAssignment]
  pivot(min(UserID) for  [RightID] in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])) as t
```

[image: test]

If I could merge lines with the same non-null value into one, I would be able to simulate the layout I expect.

Do you know how to do this?
Any better idea to generate this double entry grid?